# How to open a ".sos" file without crashing QGIS?

Tags: qgis, error, sos

I am trying to open a ".sos" file in QGIS. I have QGIS installed using OSGeo4W and added the gdal-sosi package. This should do the trick.

But QGIS just shuts down when I try to open the file. It does not give me any error message.

Do anyone know how I can solve this? I know I can do this in ArcGIS, but I prefer to do it in open source.

Comment: can you give us a sample file to test? Please describe your system and QGIS version.

Comment: Of course =) 
System: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit
QGIS version: QGIS Desktop 2.8.2. 
Sample file: Where can I send it? It is not availiable online.

Comment: @PernilleP You can use the Sosicon tool for converting sos files.

Comment: Opening SOSI files using gdal-sosi works excellent for me on Ubuntu, and it also works on Windows.  But I seem to recall that there used to be problems with SOSI (gdal-sosi) in the OSGeo4W 64 bit version - I think one had to use the 32 bit version to make it work.

Comment: QGIS 3.8.3 (64 bit) handles SOSI-files. Just click and drag them into QGIS. The "file will be split" into one layer per geometry (points, lines, polygon) depending on the content of the SOSI-file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the **Sosicon** tool could be a better option. This is a conversion tool for Norwegian map *.sos data. I copied this *.sos sample file, https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/ticket/3638/20BygnAnlegg.SOS, as **20BygnAnlegg.sos**. Afterward, I downloaded the Sosicon Windows tool from here:

http://sosicon.espenandersen.no/download/

and put the executable file and the *.sos file in the same folder. In MS-DOS console, I ran (in this folder):

```
sosicon -2shp 20BygnAnlegg.sos
```

The result was succesfully (see next image):

[image]

In QGIS, I loaded two of the several shapefiles produced. It worked!

[image]

Comment: I also found this option and it workes well! =) Still, it would be nice to have a tool in QGIS that read the files directly. Thanks for the good suggestion! =)